# Find and replace strings using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace strings in a document that enclosed in single quotes, to a string without.

```
'test' -> test
```

Is there a way using `sed` I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove single quotes from around *any* quoted word, and leave other quotes alone:

```
sed -E "s/'([a-zA-Z]*)'/\1/g"
```

When tested:

```
foo 'bar' it's 'OK' --> foo bar it's OK
```

Notice that it left the quote in `it's` intact.

Explanation:

The search regex `'([a-zA-Z]*)'` is matching any word (letters, no spaces) surrounded by quotes and using brackets, it captures the word within. The replacement regex `\1` refers to "group 1" - the first captured group (ie the bracketed group in the search pattern - the word)

FYI, here's the test:

```
echo "foo 'bar' it's 'OK'" | sed -E "s/'([a-zA-Z]*)'/\1/g"
```

Answer (score 2):

removing single quotes for certain word (text in your example):

```
kent$  echo "foo'text'000'bar'"|sed "s/'text'/text/g"
footext000'bar'
```

Comment: can be a bit DRYer: `sed "s/'\(test\)'/\1/g"

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$> cat foo
"test"
"bar"
baz "blub"

"one" "two" three

$> cat foo | sed -e 's/\"//g'
test
bar
baz blub

one two three
```

**Update**
As you only want to replace "test", it would more likely be:

```
$> cat foo | sed -e 's/\"test\"/test/g'
test
"bar"
baz "blub"

"one" "two" three
```

Comment: I don't want to find every single place where the quotes are though. Just around one word, which is 'test'

Comment: Ah. That wasn't clear from your question. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @terrid25, really important to put these details in the question, not buried in comments. Please edit your question.